# Add table row to different database using button

Tags: database, button, bootstrap-4, row

How do I get the add button to work?

I the question with a image here.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/380190/196184

When I click it I want to get the user from 'User List' to the admin table instead of typing the name and email in myself (that works). But I can't get the add button to work.

Comment: **Welcome to Stackoverflow**, `to maximise your chance of getting an answer`, please take the time to read **https://stackoverflow.com/tour** and **https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask**. `The Wordpress tag is for programming-specific questions about the WordPress content management system ONLY.` Off-topic questions include those about theme development, WordPress administration, management best practices, server configuration, etc. These are best asked on the dedicated WordPress Development Stack Exchange site (**https://wordpress.stackexchange.com**).

Comment: @amarinediary this is not only wordpress specific but I use this on my wordpress website.